# What is the best way to make QT's virtual keyboard recognize the datatype of the text field and give the appropriate keypads?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I tried my lucks with setInputMethodHints.

ms_pTextInput->setInputMethodHints(Qt::ImhPreferNone);

Anyone can help?

Comment: please provide [mcve], please clarify the question. what's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.